# How can I find what parameters the `compile` method can accept?

Tags: gradle

In `build.gradle`, we can define the dependencies like:

```
 project(':') {
    dependencies {
      compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
      compile('joda-time:joda-time:2.1')
      compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1', 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
    }
  }
```

My question is, how can I find out what types of parameter that `compile` can accept? I read this document https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html, but can't get enough information.

I also want to know, if following(mixing string and array) is correct:

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1', ['com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1', 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.7']
```

Which is working, but I'm not sure if that's really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'compile' is not a method, but a Dependency Configuration and it accepts a list of dependencies. Each dependency represented by, at least, group id, artifact id and version.

You can read more here: [8.3. Dependency configurations](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) and here: [23.5. Dependency management](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations)